# How to check if two samples come from the same population?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, nonparametric

I was wondering if or which tests can be used to test if two samples come from the same population for data that is not normally distributed?

Comment: Well, there are tests for whether the distributions from which the samples were drawn were different (against a null of the same distribution), under some simple assumptions. One example is a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. I believe this question has been asked before; I'll try to find you a link.

Comment: Duplicates 1:[Test of whole distribution for two samples](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96627/test-of-whole-distribution-for-two-samples)

2: [Given two sets how can I say statistically if they are similar or different](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92085/given-two-sets-how-can-i-say-statistically-if-they-are-similar-different)

3: [Similarity between two sets of random values](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77888/similarity-between-two-sets-of-random-values)

Comment: 4: [How do I test if two non-normal distributions differ?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87921/how-do-i-test-if-two-non-normal-distributions-differ)